Algorithm to utilize subsets of cache
We are using an external library for caching. How it implements caching is by creating a hash of all the arguments passed to the function and uses the hash as filename of the cached file. The result of the function is saved as contents of the file. The result is a dataset. Next time someone calls the same function with same arguments it will use this cached file to return the same dataset instead of running the function.
Now, we want a modification to the caching mechanism. We have few arguments of the function which can take more than one value. Let me add some examples -

country can take values as one or more country code or "all". So valid values are "all", ("IND", "USA", "CHN") , "IND" 
year can take values as one or more years or "all". So valid values are "all", (1998, 2005, 2017), (2015, 2016).
arg1 can take one or more floating values. Eg - (1.7), (1.2, 1.9, 2.5).

Let's take some example function calls considering the cached function is called cache_fun

cache_fun(country = "all", year = "all", arg1 = (1.7, 2.5, 3.4))
cache_fun(country = "IND", year = "all", arg1 = 1.7)
cache_fun(country = "CHN", year = 2015, arg1 = 3.4)

Output of 1. has values for all countries and all years for these arguments (1.7, 2.5, 3.4) and output of 2. and 3. are actually subset of 1. but because of how the current caching mechanism is implemented it does not understand that. The cache function hashes the arguments passed so the hash generated for these 3 calls is completely different so it does not utilize the cache. Ideally what I would expect is after running 1. and saving the output as cache, for 2. and 3. it should subset the cache and return relevant result.
One approach that I was thinking is create copies of result when argument is "all" and replace it with all the countries and same for year with all possible values that it can take. However, this would waste a lot of memory and I still do not know how would I subset the result. Another approach that I had thought was to loop over all the values of year, country and arg1 and call cache_fun for each unique combination. That would practically work but functions within cache_fun are written in such a way that they handle multiple values in one go (vectorized). So implementing this approach would negate the benefit that I get from vectorization of these functions, I would prefer not to go this route.
Is there any existing solution that can do what I am asking for? If not, what algorithm should I use to implement this from scratch.
I want to keep this problem (and solution) language agnostic but if it matters I am adding some context. I am using R language and the caching library that I am using is called cachem

Is it empirically shown that accesses to cache "subsets" are common enough to warrant the additional effort, for example due to a "drill down" usage pattern? If it's not clear that there is a measurable improvement, don't waste time on it (first rule of optimization).

i'd love to see how this supposed "vectorisation" would work.

Well, R has this inbuilt vectorization for many functions. For example, sqrt(1:10) gives square root of values from 1 to 10. This is how we access it at R level. R is written in C so the loop is in the underline C code. @gnasher729

Get rid of the lib. Add sqlite and store results there. You can then retrieve them by any query you want. Because that's what you really need: a database.

I think we are poking here a lot in the dark because this question makes a really bad job in explaining what the function in stake actually does.

@DocBrown Unfortunately, I cannot change the function. I have intentionally omitted what the function does because the question is not about it.

Ronak, so you have intentionally omitted would could actually be helpful. If you cannot change the function, leave it as it is.

@RonakShah: I am not talking about changing the function. If you can give a better explanation what this function does would help readers to give you a better answer. Currently, it looks like your function is some kind of SQL query? Like SELECT (whatever) FROM x where country  IN (allyears) AND year IN (allyears) AND arg1 IN (1.7, 2.5, 3.4)"? But your comment about vectorization shows me some lack of understanding here.

... I will be happy to revoke my close vote ("needs details or clarity") after we got a better explanation.

So your "cache" creates one individual file for each unique request? And practically everything you ever pass to "arg" will be a unique request? So after a million requests your server has stored half a million files?
Something that you might try: If you can create the data for YEAR = (1998, 2005, 2017) from the three results for individual years, then make separate requests for YEAR = 1998, YEAR = 2005, YEAR = 2017 and combine the results. Make sure that finding nothing for one or two of three years doesn't report a "year not found error" or similar.
Better would be to do this in the caching software, which can store the data for individual years, split the request into three lookups, do three lookups for individual years, and return the combined result, without having multiple commands and results.
If the file contains for example a completely formatted pdf file with all the information you need, which is hard to combine, then you cache the information in a format that is easier to process, and return the combined result with practically the same code as now.
PS. If you can turn this into vectorised code on your local machine, with data in memory, then writing and reading one file per request is unlikely to be a winning strategy. Measure the speed with and without caching.

This might also be smarter if the multi-value arguments are not subsets but intersect. When one call uses (1998,2005,2017) and another uses (1998,2002,2005) having the data for 1998 and 2005 would help, even though there is no subset relation.

Hi @gnasher729 , thank you for your response. However, I do not want to make a separate call for each year (or any argument for that matter). Output of the function is a dataset. I have updated my question to add more details.

My advise depends heavily on you being able/willing to change your main algorithm. As I understand it, your current algorithm takes three sets of values (countries, years and arguments) to perform some parallel calculation. If you can change your algorithm to perform the parallel calculations on a set of tuples, each tuple consisting of 1 country, 1 year and 1 argument, then you can change your caching strategy like this:

From the function arguments create your set of tuples
For each tuple, look it up in the cache, using a hash of the tuple as key

If found, set the result aside for inclusion in the result-set
If not found, add the tuple to the set to be calculated


If the set to be calculated is non-empty

Run the algorithm over that set
Store the result-set entries corresponding with each calculated tuple in the cache, keyed on the hash of the corresponding tuple


Combine the calculated and cached result-sets and return the result.

This re-uses as many entries from the cache as possible, even when different arguments are used.
